# How much money can I bring to Russia

Tags: money, russia

How many Rubles can I bring to Russia?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: The usual line is: Any amount as long as you can show provenance of the money you're declaring to customs.

Comment: 1) What is your citizenship. 2) Where are you coming from? 3) Are you asking how much you can take in absolute terms, or how much you can take without declaring it, or without paying fees, or without some other inconvenience?

Comment: Convert them into gold, it worked for me

Answer (score 5):

According to [saint-petersburg.com](http://www.saint-petersburg.com/essentials/customs/):

> Cash over $3000
>
> You are entitled to import/export up to $10000 USD in cash into Russia, but sums over $3000 should be declared at customs. This applies to all foreign currencies and to rubles, with the exact quantities varying slightly from currency to currency. The most important reason for doing this (apart from your legal obligation) is to ensure that you will be able to take your money out of the country unimpeded. If you try to leave Russia with more than $3000 in cash and no stamped customs declaration, you are likely to run into difficulties unless you have official documentation proving that the money has legally been earned by you in Russia.

Comment: Great answer.  I would be surprised if somebody could accumulate that many rubles outside of Russia.   Hard to know what the OP has in mind :)

Comment: I think it's more of a matter of "would" rather then "could"